# delete selected items in shoping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i made something like a shoping cart which you can drag items to a selected section and they will appear there. im now trying to add the option to delete a specific selected item but i could not find a proper way to do so. any suggestions?

```
<section id="productCatalog">
    <div class="product">
        <h2 class="des">Product 1 </h2>
        <p class="description"> price: </p>
        <p class="price">400</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <h2 class="des">Product 2 </h2>
        <p class="description"> price: </p>
        <p class="price">200</p>
    </div>

<section id="shoppingCart">
    <h2 align="center">shopping cart</h2>
   </section>
```

the script:

```
$(function(){
    $('.product').draggable({ 
        scroll: false, 
        containment: 'document' , 
        revert: true,
        start: function()
        {
            contents = $(this).text();
        }
     });

 $('#shoppingCart').droppable({ hoverClass: 'border', accept: '.product', drop: function()
      {
         $('#shoppingCart').append(contents + "<button id='butt' onclick='one()'>delete item</button>" + "<br>") 
      }}); 

      function one()
      {

      }
});
```

Comment: Are you using `jquery ui`? if so, please tag it in question. Also, providing a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with whatever you've working including the css would be helpful...

Comment: JQuery for handeling the shopping cart? Good news for hackers... Security issues are coming!

Comment: it's just a sample im making, it's not the real thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html**

```
<section id="shoppingCart" class="ui-droppable">
    <h2 align="center">shopping cart</h2>
   <div>
        Product 1 
         price: 
        400
       </div>
    <button id="butt" onclick="one(this);">delete item</button><br></section>
```

**js**

```
function one(obj){
    var item = $(obj).prev().andSelf().remove();    
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8JGc/6/)

Comment: I'd call it jQuery… :)

Comment: The power of habit :)

Comment: i need the option of deletion only for the items i put in the section. like if someone wants to delete something from their selection list

Comment: And where is selection list?

Comment: #shoppingcart. sorry that i can't present it to you as it is i don't know how to use the jsfiddle

Comment: just post `html` in your original post.

Comment: And how to you add products to the cart?

Comment: all works perfectly fine for me except for the "delete item" which is what im asking for right here. but it's ok don't bother i'll try and figure that out myself. thank you :)

Comment: Wrap your text around a `span` or `div` and then use this http://jsfiddle.net/p8JGc/6/